# Finder windows show up in all my Spaces

Tags: macos, spaces

When I open multiple Finder windows in Mountain Lion, I find that, no matter what virtual desktop I go to in Spaces, all the Finder windows remain where they are. However, when I open, say, Skype, for example, the window only stays in one of my virtual desktops, as expected. When I 4 finger swipe to another Space, the Skype window disappears. Why doesn't Finder do this? It's really bugging me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You just need to ctrl + click on the Finder Icon in the Dock. Go to the Options, and choose how the finder windows show in Desktops

[image]

- **All Desktops**

All Window show in Desktop Spaces

- **This Desktop**

All Window show Only in the current Desktop Space.
When your are in another desktop space it will jump to the one for finder when you open folders into windows or switch to the finder.

- **None**

Each finder windows will stick to the desktop space you open them in.

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked perfectly :D I can't believe I never thought of that!
Also +1 for the screen shot :)

Comment: This was annoying me to no end, thank you! I selected "None" and now it works as expected!

Comment: Note to those considering this fix: it will allow you to assign a specific finder window instance to a space, but it will also assign your Desktop to one space only. New finder windows automatically open on that specified space too.